# How to insert N characters into cout?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, cout

I'm rolling my own StringRef class (consisting of a `char*` into memory, and a `size_t` length) and I'm stuck implementing `operator<<`.  Is there a way (other than creating either a temporary null-terminated char array or a `std::string`) in which to insert N characters into the `cout` object?

UPDATE: to clarify:

StringRef is an object consisting of a pointer into memory (into a buffer, in my case), and a length .  The buffered data is not null-terminated; I can compute the length, which I store in the StringRef object.  I want to overload >> for this object.  The only kinds of "strings" I know how to insert into cout are null-terminated char arrays, and std::strings.  How does one insert the N characters pointed to by a StringRef [where N is the length] into cout?

Comment: [`std::ostream::write`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write)?

Comment: Not understanding what you mean. You are trying to overload the `<<` operator for a `StringRef` object? Is that what you are looking to do?

Comment: Yes, and in the overloaded operator you have an `std::ostream` reference.

Comment: Well if you are not looking to store the characters in some sort of array, how else were you planning on storing them?

Comment: Yes.  Overloading the << operator for a StringRef object.  Filling in the missing piece in the following: std::ostream&                                                                          operator<<(std::ostream& os, const StringRef& obj) {return os;}

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: std::ostream::write appears to be what I need.

Comment: Are you trying to write the member `char *` `N` times by using operator overloading ?

Comment: @P0W: no.  Please see update above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual solution for such low level types is to output
directly to the streambuf:

```
std::ostream&
operator<<( std::ostream& dest, StringRef const& obj )
{
    std::ostream::sentry s( dest );
    if ( s ) {
        std::streambuf* sb = dest.rdbuf();
        if ( sb == nullptr ) {
            dest.setstate( std::ios_base::badbit );
        } else if ( sb->sputn( obj.characters, obj.count ) != obj.count ) {
            dest.setstate( std::ios_base::badbit );
        }
    }
    return dest;
}
```

For complex types, this is much less convenient, because there
is no formatting, but for simple types like yours, it is
probably the preferred solution.

Comment: Is this preferable to simply using std::ostream::write(obj.ptr, obj.count)?

Comment: In general, yes, although both approaches are valid.  In the more general case, to use `ostream::write`, you might have to format into a specific buffer, but even then, it could be a valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it

```
friend std::ostream& operator << (ostream &oss, StringRef &obj) {
    oss << obj.characters;
    return oss;
}
```

To use it with the range based for-loop, your StringRef class should look something like:

```
class StringRef {
    //... some other variables
    char *characters;
    int count;
public:
    //...Other methods
    const char *begin() { return &characters[0]; }
    const char *end() { return &characters[count]; }
};
```